# ListView bound to a derived collection not updating (XAML / Windows 8)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, observablecollection

I'm trying to pivot my data by creating a 'view' of an Observable Collection based on certain criteria. Here's a simple example.

I have two ListViews. One is bound directly to a collection of `Dates`, the other is bound to a `DatesAfterToday` collection derived from the first collection using `Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Today)`

When I add a new item to my `Dates` collection, only the first ListView changes. The ListView bound to `DatesAfterToday` does not update at all. I've tried adding a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to the viewmodel and firing it when the dates collection is updated, but it's not working.

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="ListOne" ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="ListTwo" ItemsSource="{Binding DatesAfterToday}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Press Me to Add a Date</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Model()
    {
        _Dates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
    }
    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> _Dates;
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> Dates
    {
        get
        {
            return _Dates;
        }
        set
        {
            _Dates = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null){
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_Dates"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dates"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DatesAfterToday"));
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> DatesAfterToday 
    { 
        get {
            return new ObservableCollection<DateTime>(
                _Dates.Where(t => t.Date > DateTime.Today).ToList()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class ListTest : Page
{
    public Model model;
    public ListTest()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        model = new Model();
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0));
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 0, 0, 0));
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0));
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0));
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0));
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.Dates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 24, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Edited the question to make it a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `Model` constructor as follows:

```
public Model()
{
    _Dates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();

    _Dates.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DatesAfterToday"));
            }
        };
}
```

The thing is that when you add/remove items from the `_Dates` collection, the setter won't be called, and that's why the property change event for `DatesAfterToday` is never raised.

For collections, WPF also registers for the `CollectionChanged` event, which is exposed by the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface implemented by `ObservableCollection`. So what you can do is raise the notification for `DatesAfterToday` whenever the `_Dates` collection is modified.